Raspberry 5 won't boot without a keyboard (but with a display connected)
I'm running a half headless set-up where I have a screen attached to a Raspberry Pi, but no keyboard. It runs Kodi (installed just as a regular Debian package from the repo) and is controlled using a remote that sends a small subset of key-codes.
Recently I upgraded it from RPi4 to RPi5. I reinstalled the SD card with a fresh 2024-07-04-raspios-bookworm-arm64-lite (and apt upgrade the system afterwards).
Since then, it won't boot unless there is a keyboard attached. Without one it just loads what I'd call an "embedded installer" that looks similar to this:

I tried looking through raspi-config and also the config.txt parameters, but I couldn't find anything that would help.
Output of rpi-eeprom-config:
[all]
BOOT_UART=1
POWER_OFF_ON_HALT=0
BOOT_ORDER=0xf461

# For more options and information see
# http://rptl.io/configtxt
# Some settings may impact device functionality. See link above for details

# Use pagesize of 4kb
kernel=kernel8.img

# Uncomment some or all of these to enable the optional hardware interfaces
#dtparam=i2c_arm=on
#dtparam=i2s=on
#dtparam=spi=on

# Enable audio (loads snd_bcm2835)
dtparam=audio=on

# Additional overlays and parameters are documented
# /boot/firmware/overlays/README

# Automatically load overlays for detected cameras
camera_auto_detect=1

# Automatically load overlays for detected DSI displays
display_auto_detect=1

# Automatically load initramfs files, if found
auto_initramfs=1

# Enable DRM VC4 V3D driver
dtoverlay=vc4-kms-v3d
max_framebuffers=2

# Don't have the firmware create an initial video= setting in cmdline.txt.
# Use the kernel's default instead.
disable_fw_kms_setup=1

# Run in 64-bit mode
arm_64bit=1

# Disable compensation for displays with overscan
disable_overscan=1

# Run as fast as firmware / board allows
arm_boost=1

[cm4]
# Enable host mode on the 2711 built-in XHCI USB controller.
# This line should be removed if the legacy DWC2 controller is required
# (e.g. for USB device mode) or if USB support is not required.
otg_mode=1

[cm5]
dtoverlay=dwc2,dr_mode=host

[all]
usb_max_current_enable=1
enable_uart=1  # I just tried to enable UART as an experiment, no effect.
console=serial0
uart_2ndstage=1


None of my Pi have keyboards.

so, without a keyboard, it's like you don't have your sd card inserted? I'm guessing what you mean by "the new standard installer"

No, the SD card is there with a working system. If I plug in the keyboard and reboot (power down and up), it boots just fine.
@Milliways Just a thought, do they have screens connected? I wonder if that could make a difference (no screen + no keyboard, vs screen + no keyboard).

Does it boot if you detach the monitor and use a remote protocol like ssh, vnc, xrdp etc. to to verify that the has booted? The other possibility is the SD card is failing and the issue is unrelated to the keyboard.

Could you post your config.txt?  I don't see how what you're describing is possible with the default configuration as the keyboard isn't even a block device so it should not be affecting the boot process at all.

Also could you post the output of 'rpi-eeprom-config'

maybe the problem is caused by controlled using a remote that sends a small subset of key-codes

@jsotola Good point, I'll try booting without it (although it'd be quite inconvenient to unplug it for each reboot).

@JohnHawthorne Added my configs, thanks!

@user68186 I tried unplugging the monitor completely, but it didn't help - the device just doesn't boot from the SD card.
The SD card should be just fine. With a keyboard attached, it boots reliably. Also I used the SD card with my previous RPi4 for a long time without any issues.
So the issue is more likely in the remote control receiver, as suggested by jsotola.

You need to clarify what you mean by this: "new standard installer, offering me to install the system from scratch", because this is not really a thing unless you mean the raspi-config interface that loads on a fresh RpiOS install (which is still not a "standard installer" of anything); it is not even clear what OS you are using since you refer to Kodi, but Kodi is not a stand-alone OS.  Do you mean libre  elec?  OSMC?  How old is this system (previously used on a Pi 4)? Whatever it is, please clarify that context in detail.

@goldilocks I added a picture how (approximately) the installer looks like. It's automatically run by the RPi during the boot sequence for reasons unclear to me. I use a fresh install of 2024-07-04-raspios-bookworm-arm64-lite - I discarded the filesystem of the old RPi4, just reinstalled the same packages from scratch.

How did you install the image?  Here's the big problem here: Neither the Pi 5 nor bookworm is particularly new, and I don't think we've had any reports like this here.  I normally use the lite version, and plugging in a monitor w/o a keyboard on a new install is not unusual -- but I have never seen this screen.  I do not use the rpi imager to do installs, though, and this looks like a screenshot from that, ie., it implies to me this is part of some kind of multi-stage install that the imager is responsible for.  But that is just a casual guess, and I am not saying you are for sure wrong.

Right now, though, pretty much everyone is going to look at this and think, "I don't know what you've done wrong", so there is no potential answer, it will just get ignored.  If you really want to try and make this case, you have to demonstrate this is reproducible following a very specific set of steps.  That means: 1) You detach all other hardware from the Pi other than the monitor -- you mention "controlled using a remote" but you do not say anything about what that is; 2) Start with a fresh, new image, and explain every single step involved in putting it on the card.

If after that you still have the same issue, then you have a problem other people can help investigate further.  If not, or if you cannot fulfil both those criteria precisely, then all anyone can say is, "You're doing your own thing, I don't know exactly what it is, so it is a waste of time for me to think about it."

@goldilocks Thank you for your comprehensive comments. What you're saying does make sense. I'll try to figure out exact steps how to reproduce the issue, and if I manage, I'll report back.
